# Error: Option 'debug-counter' registered more than once

Tags: llvm

I have a error when open the following programs:

**LxTerminal, Octopi, Qemu, Google Chrome, Geany, CodeBlocks, Blender, Baobab, Czkawka, Peek, FSearch, Gnumeric, QT Designer, Gtk3-Demo, KNewStuff Dialog, Warzone 2100, PyChess and Gxine**.

And fails on  open Nouveau video driver, maybe by this error.

```bash
: CommandLine Error: Option 'debug-counter' registered more than once! LLVM ERROR: inconsistency in registered CommandLine options
Abortado
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found at the moment is to delete the files started in **libLLVM** from the system.

```bash
mkdir -p /usr/lib/.llvm-tmp
mv  /usr/lib/libLLVM* /usr/lib/.llvm-tmp/libLLVM*
```

This allows me to open the following programs:

**LxTerminal, Qemu, Google Chrome, Geany, CodeBlocks, Baobab, Czkawka, Peek, FSearch, Gnumeric, QT Designer, Gtk3-Demo and PyChess.**

But...

The **Warzone 2100** is impossible to open because **Mesa** depends on *LLVM*.